# Hibernate3 and spring social facebook authentication

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am going to integrate the spring facebook login with hibernate. I have implemented the following configuration but not working yet.

When I click on the login with facebook button, it is get redirected to facebook login page but when I click on login button I got the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select userId from UserConnection where providerId = ? and providerUserId = ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.userconnection' doesn't exist
```

My xml configuration is as:-

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="url" value="${url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driver}" />
        <!-- <property name="maxActive" value="${pool.max_active}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${pool.max_idle}" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="${pool.max_wait}" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" /> -->
    </bean>
    <bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.security.core.filter.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler"></bean>
    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.security.core.filter.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"></bean>   
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value=" />
        <!-- <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value></value>
                <value></value>
            </list>
        </property> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
                <prop key="connection.pool_size">1</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">60</prop>

                    <!-- <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">managed</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nuts2invest" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="dbHelper" class="com.server.db.dao.HibernateUtil">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>




   <!-- ================= Facebook Configuration ============== -->


    <!-- This is used to hash the password of the user. -->
    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        Configures the social authentication filter which integrates Spring Social
        with Spring Security.
    -->
    <bean id="socialAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="userIdSource"/>
        <constructor-arg index="2" ref="usersConnectionRepository"/>
        <constructor-arg index="3" ref="connectionFactoryLocator"/>

        <!-- Sets the url of the registration form. -->
        <property name="signupUrl" value="/onRegisterClick"/> 
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="locator" class="org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionFactory"></bean> -->
    <!--
        Configures the social authentication provider which processes authentication requests
        made by using supported social authentication services (FB, Twitter and so on).
    -->
    <bean id="socialAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationProvider">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="usersConnectionRepository"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="socialUserDetailsService"/>
    </bean>

    <!--
        This bean is used to load the user specific data when social sign in
        is used.
    -->
    <bean id="socialUserDetailsService" class="com.nuts2invest.security.SimpleSocialUserDetailsService">
<!--         <constructor-arg index="0" ref="userDetailsService"/>
 -->    </bean>

    <!--
        This bean determines the account ID of the user. The example application
        uses the username as the account ID.
    -->
    <bean id="userIdSource" class="org.springframework.social.security.AuthenticationNameUserIdSource"/>

    <bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" class="org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationServiceRegistry">
        <property name="authenticationServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.security.FacebookAuthenticationService">
                    <constructor-arg value="rer4343434"/>
                    <constructor-arg value="43434rererererer3434" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="textEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors" 
        factory-method="noOpText" />

    <bean id="usersConnectionRepository" class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository" 
            factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
        <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/>
    </bean>

     <!-- <facebook:config app-id="xxxyyyzzz" app-secret="zzzyyyxxx"/> -->

     <!-- <social:jdbc-connection-repository/>   -->


    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
        <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080/war" />
         <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the other constructor-args -->    
    </bean>
```

Comment: The exception is quite clear... Table `test.userconnection` doesn't exist` there is no table `userconnection` in the `test` schema.

Comment: yes thanks,but I have created different table with named as 'user' mapped with another table. When user registred himself then user data is stored in User table. Then why it is searching for userconnection table. and what will be the columns in users connection table.

Comment: User != userconnection. I suggest a read of the Spring SOcial documentation. The `userconnection` table is used to store the connections to service providers for a user.

Comment: Actually I have tested it by creating userconnection table in my test db. But I am not getting what type data should I stored into userconnection table or service provider will automatically insert the data into userconnection table. when I tested by creating such table then also I am getting the error.

Comment: No you are creating a table `connection`.... Also please don't post code as a comment it makes it totally unreadable.

Comment: I suggest using the `JdbcUserConnectionRepository.sql` from the `org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc` package to create the desired table.

Comment: sorry,I test it by creating userconnection table. thanks..

Comment: I have created table userconnection but getting error as HTTP Status 404 - /war/signup and url generated is http://localhost:8080/war/signup#_=_..

Comment: @M.Deinum ,How the data is stored in userconnection table? I have some doubts as:-1) I have registered the user in simple way. I can login by simple username and password. But when I login facebook with the same name,it is not redirected to my application, because it finds the user in userconnection table which does not have any records.So plz tell,how the records is stored in userconnection table?

Comment: As mentioned read the docs. Spring Social (the connect controller in this case) stores information in there.

Comment: I have read the spring doc,and implemented the Connect Controller as shown in above code but its not working..

Comment: @M. Deinum ,Can u plz help me to resolve this issue, i am stuck over here.thanks in advance..